# How to configure grails app to write logs, stack traces, and errors to a specific file

Tags: tomcat, grails, log4j

I want my grails application to log all debugs, stack traces, uncaught errors (500s etc) to be logged to a specific file `myapp.log` in tomcat. At the moment everything is being logged to `catalina.out`. Which isn't desirable as there might be other applications deployed on the Tomcat instance.

My config looks like this. I am using grails `2.2.4`

```
log4j = {
    appenders {
        console name: "stdout", layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "%c{2} %m%n")
    }

    root {
        info "stdout"
    }

    debug "com.myapp.mypackage",
          "grails.app.controllers.com.myapp.mycontrollers"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd put this in an `environments` block to make sure it only applies to the production environment. You can easily add a file appender in the `appenders` section, and the Grails docs show how to configure it as a rolling appender to create new files every day, or once a file has reached a maximum size, etc. 'Attach' the appender to the `root` level in place of the `console` appender:

```
environments {
   production {
      log4j = {
         appenders {
            console name: "stdout",
                    layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "%c{2} %m%n")

            file name: 'mylog',
                 file: '/var/logs/mylog.log',
                 layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "%c{2} %m%n")
         }

         root {
            info "mylog"
         }

         debug "com.myapp.mypackage",
               "grails.app.controllers.com.myapp.mycontrollers"

      }
   }
}
```

Configuring logging using the Log4j DSL is pretty confusing, but the docs explain a lot and have a bunch of helpful examples: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#logging